# Erro net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ao fazer requisição Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Me deparei com um erro estranho quando tentei executar uma requisição ajax, e não tive muito sucesso na procura de soluções.

Eis o erro:

[image: Erro jQuery]

A linha 199 do `forms.js` é o **`$.ajax({`** em:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: _url,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        type: 'excluir',
        key: _data
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //success
    }
});
```

PS.: Já tentei trocando `$` para `jQuery` mas não funcionou.
PS. 2: As referências e chamadas das bibliotecas jQuery estão na ordem correta.

O mais estranho, é que esse mesmo arquivo funciona parada todas as outras páginas, já que ele é meu arquivo global para tratamento de formulários.

Comment: como está a defenir o `_url`?

Comment: _url é uma variável do próprio arquivo que retorna a página aberta.

Comment: É um post para a mesma página, ou para um server diferente? Pode ser necessidade de `CORS` habilitado no server, se for domínio/protocolo/porta diferente

Comment: É para a mesma página. Como pode ver no erro, estou tentando enviar da página "banner.php", ou seja, `_url = 'banner.php';`. Estou rodando em modo local, via xampp, tudo padrão.

Comment: Vitor, a minha questao é se está a usar path relativo ou nao. Isso pode ser visto como CORS

Comment: Não, Sergio. Está utilizando apenas o nome do arquivo como referência, como comentei logo ali (`_url = 'banner.php';`)

Comment: Bom, dei uma vasculhada maior e encontrei referências neste link https://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=6369. Testei no firefox (e funcionou). Na realidade, não era erro de código nem nada, era apenas o Adblock (extensão do chrome) bloqueando a requisição. Caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema futuramente, basta adicionar o domínio à lista de permitidos.

Comment: Que tal colocar o comentário como resposta e marcar como resolvido?

Comment: Victor, acho que vale a pena juntar essa informacao como resposta

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bom, dei uma vasculhada maior e encontrei referências [neste link](http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=6369).

Testei no firefox (e funcionou). Na realidade, não era erro de código nem nada, era apenas o Adblock (extensão do chrome) bloqueando a requisição.

Caso alguém venha a ter o mesmo problema futuramente, basta adicionar o domínio (**mesmo se for localhost**) à lista de permitidos.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkk tenso quando o tiro sai pela culatra. Mas era isso mesmo. Bastou eu pausar o AddBlock que o erro não ocorreu mais. Obrigado.

Comment: puts, tive que alterar o caminho.... kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Só para ajudar quem está vendo essa resposta: Provavelmente o adblock bloqueou essa requisição porque tinha a palavra `banner` na URL. Mesmo que você pause o adblock pra desenvolver, esse AJAX talvez não funcione pra algum usuário que está usando adblock (pois ele não pausou o adblock no seu site, e provavelmente nem vai). Minha sugestão é trocar a palavra `banner` da url pra alguma outra palavra.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, utilize a seguinte técnica:
http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Isso era dar acesso aos arquivos locais.
Por padrão o Chrome bloqueia o acesso aos arquivos locais.

Comment: Nunca sofri esse problema, a causa foi simplesmente o AdBlock Plus. Mas permanece e agradeço a dica ;)

Answer (score 0):

A **extensão do Avast** bloqueia alguns scripts de análise (Google Analytics, por exemplo) e redes sociais.

**Basta adicionar os domínios dos scripts bloqueados como exceção** nas configurações da extensão do Avast que ele passa a permitir a execução desses scripts.

Além disso o **AddBlock** também bloqueia alguns recursos, como o mend3 disse na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8794/298),